# Passing code parameters through a file "parameters.txt"

Tags: r, input, parameter-passing

I want to make my code easily usable from other users. In order to do that I want to provide a file "parameters.txt" in which a user can easily change the values. I'd like also to insert comments in it (such to make it clearer). It has to be something like:

```
# File of parameters
#
# Here put the year you want to analyze.
# You can choose:
# 1) 2000
# 2) 2001
# 3) 2002
# 4) 2003
year    2004
# Here put the team you want to analyze
# Choose it between 
# 1) "Lazio"
# 2) "Juventus"
# 3) "Inter"
team    Lazio
```

When I read the files I don't want to take the comment. In other words, I'd like to read all the lines except the ones starting with "#".

1. Is this a good wat to pass the parameters?
2. Do you know how can I take only the lines I'm interested to?

Comment: You could do something like `xx <- readLines("/tmp/tmpfile.txt"); xx[!grepl("^#", xx)]`. As to whether or not this is a good approach, it may be more common to use a markup language like YAML for this type of thing. However, if you can ensure the parameter file(s) will always be well-formed like the above, it shouldn't be difficult to parse our parameters yourself.

Comment: `read.table` will read this file just fine. By default it skips lines that begin with `#`

Answer (score 0):

Following the advices of MrFlick I have found the solution with `read.table`:

```
parameters <- read.table("./parametri.txt",                                           
                          header = FALSE, blank.lines.skip = TRUE, comment.char="#",   
                          skip = 12     , skipNul = TRUE         , fill=TRUE)
```

supposing the parameters file is in the current folder.